# Using meteor and blaze how to convert template to string for an email body?

Tags: javascript, meteor

And how can I set the value of this now? Ie in js? All i see is how to do in handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Meteor does not natively support server side rendering of templates, and since you are sending emails from the server this creates an issue. Server side rendering is on the Meteor roadmap, but for now we can use a package. its called "Handlebars-server" and it can be found here: https://atmospherejs.com/package/handlebars-server

With Handlebars-server you can compile handlebars templates into strings for use in emails. The package's readme should get you started and show you how to set data context.

Answer (score 2):

From Meteorpedia :

http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes

Take a look at "How to render a template to HTML with data"

```
var toHTMLWithData = function (kind, data) {
    return UI.toHTML(kind.extend({data: function () { return data; }}));
};
```

Use it like this :

```
var myTemplateAsString=toHTMLWithData(Template.myTemplate,dataContext);
```

Which is equivalent to previous Spark code :

```
var myTemplateAsString=Template.myTemplate(dataContext);
```